# Deserialize json as quoted string in Jackson without annotations

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a class like this.

```java
class MyClass {
    String config;
    // ... other fields, getters, setters ...
}
```

The `config` string will be coming as JSON from the REST endpoint in the request body as follows..

```json
"config": {
   "field1": "value1",
   "field2": 2,
   "field3": true
}
// other fields of MyClass
```

I need to deserialize `MyClass` in such a way that the above JSON string is put in quotes as follows.

```
"config": "{
   \"field1\": \"value1\",
   \"field2\": 2,
   \"field3\": true
}"
```

I cannot modify this class as it is being used by other projects. So, I cannot use `@JsonDeserialize` or any annotations on the class.

I tried setting the following properties to `ObjectMapper`

```java
 mapper.configure(JsonGenerator.Feature.QUOTE_FIELD_NAMES, false)
 .configure(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_UNQUOTED_FIELD_NAMES, true);
```

Is there any other way, perhaps using `ObjectMapper` to deserialize it that way. I am using Spring Boot also, so would welcome a Spring boot Jackson way of doing this.

Comment: What you have is a JSON object whose `config` property is a String value consisting of a JSON object. You'll need to extract that property and deserialize it again.

Answer (score 1):

You can use JsonNode, the Jackson JsonNode class, com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode is Jackson's tree model (object graph model) for JSON, use like that:

```
String content = jsonNode.get("data").textValue();
```

Comment: For me the textValue is coming as `null` though the field is present

Comment: You can use jsonNode.findValue("config").toString(); instead, can you try that?